# How can I pack my images into the app?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, javacv

I have written a imageprocessing app with javacv. I have some samples which are there to find some objects on a taken picture. The problem is that my program just gets nullpointerexception.

```
static String objectFilename = "assets/sblinksoben.png";

object = cvLoadImage(objectFilename,
                CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

The first one is the path and the last one is how I load the image. Evertime when I check it with my debugger it only stands object = null.

So my guess is that the images are not getting packed into the .apk and the program will not find anything.

Does someone have solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to load files from the `assets` folder of your project.

Not sure about the `cvLoadImage()` method, but maybe it has a version which will take an `InputStream` of the image. In that case you can use `AssetManager.open()` to load the image from your assets and pass it to `cvLoadImage()`.